# Magento 1 search not working propely with polish products

Tags: magento, search

I have problem with magento 1.9 search. I using https://mirasvit.com/magento-extensions/search-autocomplete-suggestions.html extension. When I types in input e.g płaszcz (polish charakter) it working correct, but when types plaszcz (without polish charakter), it not give nothing result.

I also have other project with this extension, and there all working propely, so I copied module to my project but it same effect - not working.

where can be problem ?

Answer (score 0):

check/compare locale settings in both stores, just guessing

Comment: I compared all settings, and are same

Comment: strange. in general you could implement iconv() in search indexer or/and in frontend controller to use TRANSLIT and simplify foreign characters